# which function grows faster than the other

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

> does n^log(n) grows faster than 2^n?
>
> does n^log(n) grows faster than 4^n?

I am not able to prove or disprove which one grows faster than other I know for sure that 4^n grows faster than 2^n.

Comment: Probably a better fit for http://cs.stackexchange.com , but you have to show some effort.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for Computer Science SE!

Comment: both 2^n and 4^n grows faster than n^log(n)

Comment: Just look plot their growth http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: You say you "know for sure that 4^n grows faster than 2^n", but how do you know that? Can the reasoning that you used to know that be used for the harder problem? Without knowing where you're stuck, it's hard to give a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `n` approach infinity.

`lim n^log(n)/2^n = lim exp(log(n^log(n)/2^n)) = lim exp(log(n) * log(n) - n * log(2)) = exp(-inf) = 0`.

Thus, `2^n` grows faster than `n^log(n)`. Obviously, so does `4^n`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: let's denote log *n* as *x*; then 2<sup>*x*</sup> = *n*. Then *n*<sup>log *n*</sup> = (2<sup>*x*</sup>)<sup>*x*</sup> = 2<sup>*x*<sup>2</sup></sup>, whereas 2<sup>*n*</sup> = 2<sup>2<sup>*x*</sup></sup>. Since 2<sup>*x*</sup> grows faster than *x*<sup>2</sup>, we know that 2<sup>2<sup>*x*</sup></sup> grows faster that 2<sup>*x*<sup>2</sup></sup>, which means that 2<sup>*n*</sup> grows faster than n<sup>log *n*</sup>.